# How to invoke a method with multiple arguments in background thread in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

When I tap a button it will invoke an action which in-turn will initiate a process(through another method) and return. I thought of using

```
[<target> performSeleltorInBackgroundThread:....];
```

-but I could not pass multiple arguments through this.

How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self goDoSomethingLongAndInvolved:arg1 and:arg2 and:arg3 and:argN];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [textField setStringValue:@"Done doing something long and involved - Update UI"];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that, but you could add arguments into the array and pass this array as the only one argument into -performSelectorInBackgroundThread. With literals you could do that pretty easy:

```
NSArray *arguement = @[first, second, third];
```

in -performSelector:

```
id first = argument[0];
...
```